# Listing nodes from different for-each loop search in one variable/sequence/group

Tags: xslt, sequence

I have a problem which i don't know the solution to. I am using xslt 1.0.

My task is as following:

I have a file where there are url to different .xml files. My job is to, get the names of these files, and then iterate through each of these files looking for a tag `<Genre>`. So it can be that, in the first file I find 3 `<Genre>` elements, in the 2nd 1 `<Genre>` element ... and so on till the n-th file.

After gathering all the `<Genre>` elements from all the files, I need to sort them (they hold a string info in them, which is like their name). To sort them, I need to have ALL the `<Genre>` elements in ONE varibale/group/sequence, so that I can apply the `<xsl:sort>` on them.

But I don't know, how I can add/union/concatenate the `<Genre>` elements that I find in every loop from each of the files :(

Please please help ... I have tried now for 9 hours with no result.

The code looks approximately like below:

The xml file with the file names

```
 <document-properties>
      <source-documents>
        <document name="Input/Commandline.xml"/>
        <document name="Input/Outputfiles.xml"/>
        <document name="Input/PrimaryFunctionalities.xml"/>
        <document name="Input/Requirements.xml"/>
        <document name="Input/UsecaseTree.xml"/>
        <document name="Input/CurrentDate.xml"/>
        <document name="CommentFiles/VWCC_Test.xml"/>
        </source-documents>
    </document-properties>
```

And I am doing the following in my .xsl:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/document-properties/source-documents/*">      
  <xsl:for-each select="document(@name)/descendant::newTerm">
    <xsl:variable name="CurrentNewTerm" select="."/>

    <w:tr wsp:rsidR="00000000">
      <w:tblPrEx>
        <w:tblCellMar>
          <w:top w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
          <w:bottom w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
        </w:tblCellMar>
      </w:tblPrEx>
      <w:tc>
        <w:tcPr>
          <w:tcW w:w="2480" w:type="dxa" />
        </w:tcPr>
        <w:p wsp:rsidR="00000000" wsp:rsidRDefault="00C06CD8">
          <w:pPr>
            <w:spacing w:before="60" w:after="60" />
            <w:rPr>
              <w:b />
            </w:rPr>
          </w:pPr>
          <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
            </w:rPr>
             <w:t>                   
               <xsl:value-of select="$CurrentNewTerm"/>
             </w:t>
          </w:r>
        </w:p>
      </w:tc>

      <xsl:variable name="abbrvFileName" select="/document-properties/abbreviation-document/*[@name]"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="document($abbrvFileName)/descendant::term">

      </xsl:for-each>
      <w:tc>
        <w:tcPr>
          <w:tcW w:w="2480" w:type="dxa" />
        </w:tcPr>
        <w:p wsp:rsidR="00000000" wsp:rsidRDefault="00C06CD8">
          <w:pPr>
            <w:spacing w:before="60" w:after="60" />
            <w:rPr>
              <w:b />
            </w:rPr>
          </w:pPr>
          <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>
              <xsl:value-of select="$CurrentNewTerm"/>
            </w:t>
          </w:r>
        </w:p>
      </w:tc>
    </w:tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

As told before, in this way I get the  tags of one file at once ... but I need a way to save the "found"  tags of each for-each loop in a list/group/sequence ... so that I can do a SORT on ALL the  tags of all the files as one list.

Comment: Consider to explain your problem in more details by providing samples of the XML input documents and the corresponding output you want to create, then hopefully someone here can show you how to achieve that with XSLT. Currently your description ("iterating", "loop") is much too procedural. Reading in other documents in XSLT 1.0 can be done with the `document` function, it is quite powerful so doing `document(root/files/file)` might suffice to pull in all files linked to from your main document.

Comment: @Martin Honnen is right. If you have some nodes with URIs you can use them as `document()`'s argument and even use this primary expression as part of a relative path to `Genre` elements, all in just one liner XPath expression that could be used in any `@select` of some XSLT's instruction.

Comment: @Martin Honnen , @Alejandro: I have made my query a bit more better by adding the code I have and explaining what i want to do ... maybe you can suggest something now! thanks.

Comment: @Jasmin If your problem was solved, please post your solution as an answer and mark it as correct. I've rolled back your question text in case it is useful to other people in future.

Answer (score 0):

How are you invoking the XSLT processing from?  commandline? some programming language?

The simple approach is to concatenate all the files into one single large xml file and then pass the single large xml file into XSLT.

The technique/code to do the concatenation is going to vary depending on the language you are invoking from.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly straightforward to do with something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="document(.//url)//Genre">
  <xsl:sort select="StringInfo">
    ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Looks like that would work for only 1 document?  OP - I think - was asking to sort on Genre tags across multiple documents.

Comment: @Naraen @Michael Kay: Naraen, You are right, I am looking for to find tags from multiple documents, put them in a list, and then do a sort on ALL of them. I have made my query a bit more better by adding the code I have and explaining what i want to do ... maybe you can suggest something now! thanks.